# How to count the values in two different rows of same table?

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.4

I have a table like below:

```
emp    PR   PF
---    ---  ---
1       10   20
2       30   20
3       10   20
4        5   6
```

I am trying to count the values such that if `PF` or `PR` or both are same as emp 1 then the count should increment.

For example `emp 2` has PF same as `emp 1` so, count should be 1 here for emp 2.

I am trying to get an output like below for the given table sample:

```
emp   countVal
---   --------
2        1
3        2
```

I have written the following query using self join but it is not giving me the required output.

```
SELECT  e.emp,sum(CASE When e1.PR=e2.PR Then 1 
                       When e1.PF=e2.PF Then 1
                       Else 0 End ) as countVal
FROM
    employee e1
    INNER JOIN employee e2
        ON e1.emp=e2.emp and e1.emp!=1
        group by e1.emp
```

Can someone please tell what exactly I have to do here?

Comment: I can't get the logic. Could you explain how the first example (with emp=1,2) is related to the second "result (with emp=2,3) ? And what ebout emp=4 ?

Comment: @krokodilko It is just an example where I am showing how two rows have to be compared. And the other with (emp=2,3) is the desired output.

Comment: Question: How do you get the output where emp=3 and countVal=2? What does it sum?

Comment: @J.Francis for `emp 3`, `countVal`= 2 because on comparing with the row `emp 1`, the values of `PF` and `PR` are the same. In this case `10` and `20` for `PF` and `PR` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT e.emp,
      ( (e.PR = e1.PR)::int + (e.PF = e1.PF)::int ) as countVal
FROM employee e JOIN
     employee e1
     ON e1.emp = 1;
```

Notes:

- Aggregation is not needed.  There seems to be only one employee per row and that is what you want in the result set.
- This uses Postgres's type conversion from a boolean to an integer using `::`.

Comment: this query is only giving me emp 1. But what I am expecting as output is emp 2  and emp 3 as these are the employees who have either PF or PR or both, same as emp 1

Comment: I have updated my question. I hope the requirement would be clearer now.

Comment: @ABeginner . . . The `join` condition was not appropriate.  You basically want a `cross join`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the output won’t be like that because you need to make a combination between all the emps. There is no way to guess which are the ones you need:

```
select *, 
CAST((t1.PR = t2.PR) as int) + cast(t1.PF = t2.PF) as int) as countValue from empTable t1 
cross join empTable t2
```

Good luck!

Comment: Actually comparing the values of PF and PR of emp 1 with other employees. I needed emp 2 and emp 3 to show up in the result as these are the ones who have either PF or PR or both, same as emp 1.

Comment: @ABeginner I think this query does exactly what you said in this comment, a cross join fits perfectly for this combination. Does it?